# How can winapi SendMessage possibly allow to type any character on my keyboard?

Tags: java, winapi, sendmessage

This blew up my mind. I am reverse-engineering a Java project that aims for macro-automation of some desktop tasks. Unlike other programs, which actively move real-life cursor, this project sends messages through WinApi. This makes application think used clicked/typed while real user input isn't interrupted and other programs are not affected. I thought of similar thing long ago, but didn't know how to do that.

For typing strings in fields, the project uses surprisingly simple method:

```
  public void typeString(String text) {
   for (char key : text.toCharArray()) {
     sendMsg(258, key, 0);
   }
  }
```

Where sendMsg encloses [winapi SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, 258, key, 0);
```

Well, it's no surprise this works for things like `abcd`. But I got it work even for characters with diacritical symbols!

[image: screenshot of the code and result]

Now I expected something like broken function key actions or something like that. And my questions regarding this thing are:

1. Will this work on all platforms? At least for unicode applications?
2. How can I enter functional keys?

Comment: Well, `258` is the [`WM_CHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276(v=vs.85).aspx) flag.  You might need the `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages instead, but then you'd need to figure out the expectations of the (last) two parameters for `SendMessage`

Comment: So, I imagin an combination of `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` and the [Windows Virtual KeyCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should help...

Comment: [Simulating input via WM_CHAR messages may fake out the recipient but it won't fake out the input system](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/28/10190521.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @RemyLebeau. However if an application will be trying to detect and counteract my program, I'll probably let them do so.

Comment: How would it be able to do that? The input messages don't carry any sender information. If you're really afraid of looking like malware to a specific program, you'd probably feel more comfortable using whatever API that program exposes, if not an accessibility framework, instead. Otherwise, `SendInput()` was *designed* and is *designated* to do what you want, as the linked article explains.

Comment: That just makes me even more happy. Is there any documentation of message numbers and functions? I'd like to rewrite them in enum to make my code readable.

Comment: Err, `windows.h`? You don't have to define anything yourself, in enums or otherwise.

Comment: We're in java here. Java does not include `windows.h`. And I don't remember any standard enum dedicated for the messages.

Comment: @TomášZato `SendMessage()` is called from C or C++, and that's where you need `windows.h`. Nobody said there was a standard enum anywhere, no idea what you're talking about there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"... any character on my keyboard" really depends on your keyboard. `WM_CHAR` is documented to handle UTF-16 ***if*** the target window is Unicode (CreateWindowW). To support characters outside the [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) you should use `WM_UNICHAR`...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will keep in mind to check whether the window is unicode.